# Slow mysql query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables in my database:

product_fav:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_fav` (   
`user_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`asin` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
`price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`asin`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

product_info:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_info` (
`asin` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`brand` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`part_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`url` text,
`image` text,
`availabillity` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`asin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

product_price:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_price` (
`asin` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`asin`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT   pi.*, 
         pp.price, 
         pf.date, 
         pf.price                                          AS price_added, 
         round((100.0 (pp.price - pf.price) / pf.price),0) AS percentdiff 
FROM     product_info pi 
JOIN 
         ( 
                  SELECT   * 
                  FROM     product_price 
                  ORDER BY date DESC) pp 
ON       pp.asin = pi.asin 
JOIN     product_fav pf 
ON       pp.asin = pf.asin 
WHERE    pf.user_id=". $user['user_id'] ." 
GROUP BY asin
```

Product price has many records and query needs about 3 second. Is it possible to make it faster?

I have also the same issue with search query:

```
SELECT pi.*, 
       price, 
       date 
FROM   product_info pi 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   product_price 
             ORDER  BY date DESC) pp 
         ON pi.asin = pp.asin 
WHERE  ( ` NAME ` LIKE '%".$search."%' ) 
GROUP  BY pi.asin 
ORDER  BY price
```

EXPLAIN return this:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref           | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 106709 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pi            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 32      | pp.asin       |      1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pf            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 36      | const,pp.asin |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | product_price | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 112041 | Using filesort                  |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` unless you really need all the columns.  In particular grabbing `TEXT` columns slow down the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont `ORDER` before `JOIN`, If you need order do it after the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` so less data to sort.

```
JOIN 
         ( 
                  SELECT   * 
                  FROM     product_price 
                  ORDER BY date DESC) pp
```

Create index for asin so  `JOIN` for `ON       pp.asin = pi.asin` will be more efficient

Create index for `user_id` so the `WHERE pf.user_id=". $user['user_id'] ."` will be more efficient

Comment: If i remove order by from inner select it does not select the latest price from product price table

Comment: I see. That is a feature of Mysql I dont like because isnt the standard behaivior of db. So I suggest you search for MAX value for a group. and update your query.

Comment: Yes exactly... Using SELECT * FROM product_price WHERE date IN ('latest_date(i had it saved it)) iin the subquery improved a lot the query. Now needs 0.26s instead of 3s. Still need some help to improve the search query

Comment: No need, did the same to the search query and had the same result. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Spira - You are running an old version of MySQL; newer versions ignore the inner `ORDER BY`, thereby not letting you get the 'latest' with that trick.  Follow the groupwise max tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try running an EXPLAIN on your query to figure out where the bottle-neck is.
What's with the ORDER BY date in the inner query? Try getting rid of it. Also try replacing the inner query with a JOIN, they tend to be faster.
Also, do you have an index on the date field? Try adding one for the ORDER BY at the end of the query.

Comment: It seems that Order by heavily impacts the performance. Time decreased from 3.6 s to 0.49s. I run EXPLAIN but do not know how to explain the results that shows